# there is a way to use bootstrap based components in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I want to use tools like this http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ inside a angular2 component. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use primeng or ng2-bootstrap etc..
I personally prefer primeng.

Check the documentaion [primeng](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/)

```
npm install primeng --save
```

Comment: PrimeNG has a bootstrap theme as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this module: https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/ ?